# Unix time based sorted array is not sorting correctly

Tags: javascript, react-native, sorting

I've UNIX timestamps in a response and I'm sorting them as:

```
var sortedData = data.sort(function (x, y) {
    return x.created - y.created
})
```

Here are some of the values of `created`

```
1612840160306
1612717863299
1612715819573
1612853308834
1612842118101
1612767742861
...
```

Then I'm passing the `sortedData` to a state which then re-renders as:

```
                        {userSortedData.map((data, index) =>
                            <MyTestCell
                                key={index}
                                name={data.personName}
                                phone={data.phone}
                                createdOn={data.created}
                            />
                        )}
```

In my view, I can see that the first cell is assumed

[image]

And a cell below it is

[image]

Whereas it should be that the cell displaying Feb 7 date should be above Feb 6 but it's not.

Comment: whatever you did is working perfectly fine, but in ascending order thus you are seeing in 6th before 7th. Try descending order `data.sort((x, y) => y.created - x.created)`.

Comment: @Ravikumar thank you for pointing it out, It worked now. If you post this as an answer I'll accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you did is working perfectly fine, but in ascending order thus you are seeing in 6th before 7th. Try descending order

```
data.sort((x, y) => y.created - x.created)
```